# Ошибка must have one register DataBase alias named `default`

Tags: golang, beego

Пытаюсь сделать простой запрос к базе данных в Beego, но вылазит ошибка:

> must have one register DataBase alias named `default`

Код:

```
type User struct {
    ID int64 `orm:"auto"`
    Name string `orm:"size(128)"`
    Email string `orm:"size(128)"`
    Password string `orm:"size(34)"`
}

func GetList() []*User {
    orm.RegisterDriver("mysql", orm.DRMySQL)
    orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "mysql", "root:@127.0.0.1:3306/go?charset=utf8")
    orm.RegisterModel(new(User))

    o := orm.NewOrm()
    table := o.QueryTable("users")
    var users []*User

    _, err := table.All(&users)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return users
}
```

Comment: Нет, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто импортировать дайвер:

```
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```